# how to create a user account from root and not installing again software

Tags: kali-linux, users

Goodmorning!I have installed linux on my computer as a root and i would like to make a user account without reinstalling all the software.It is a big fatigue.I have seen doing that at Universities.How is this possible?Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Kali Linux is *designed* to be run as root:

From https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux:

> What’s Different About Kali Linux?
>
> Kali Linux is specifically geared to meet the requirements of professional penetration testing and security auditing. To achieve this, several core changes have been implemented in Kali Linux which reflect these needs:
>
> **Single user, root access by design**: Due to the nature of security audits, Kali Linux is designed to be used in a “single, root user” scenario. Many of the tools used in penetration testing require escalated privileges, and while it’s generally sound policy to only enable root privileges when necessary, in the use cases that Kali Linux is aimed at, this approach would be a burden.

Kali Linux is definitely not your average Linux, and to use it for general purpose work is not recommended in any way, shape or form. Install another Unix system if you want a general purpose system to work with.

Debian or Ubuntu may be the most obvious choices, as these Linuxes most closely resembles Kali.

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't google. Open you shell and type following command this will add new account.

`useradd username`

To set password 
`echo "your_password" | passwd --stdin username`